# Bash command that prints human readable $PATH outhput not working as an alias in .bash_profile on OS X

Tags: bash, command-line

This command prints human readable `$PATH` output.

```
tr ':' '\n' <<< "$PATH"
```

However, when I alias the command it does not work. I am sure I need to escape some of the characters, just not sure which ones or how to do it in bash.

```
alias hpath='tr ':' '/n' <<< "$PATH"'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use double quotes throughout then you can surround everything with single quotes:

```
alias hpath='tr ":" "\n" <<< "$PATH"'
```

Or to have a mix of quote types, surround the alias with double quotes and then escape all the special characters (`\"`, `\$`, etc.):

```
alias hpath="tr ':' '\n' <<< \"\$PATH\""
```

If you're curious, it's possible to use single quotes on the outside, but it's really really hairy. There's no way to escape characters in single quotes, so putting single quotes inside of single quotes requires you to type `'\''`—`'` ends the string, `\'` adds a literal quote, and `'` starts another string.

```
alias hpath='tr '\'':'\'' '\''\n'\'' <<< "$PATH"'
```

Yuck!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of invoking an external command `tr` you can do this using *BASH's string substitution*:

```
alias paths="echo \"${PATH//:/$'\n'}\""
```

Or better use a BASH function to avoid esaping:

```
mypath() {
    echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
}
```